# Order by two columns MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am implementing a Popular feature into my app where I will select the most popular posts from a database. Problem is I need to get the most popular in terms of most likes and most comments. I just tried:

```
SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY `likesCount`,`commentsCount` DESC LIMIT $from," . ($to-$from)
```

But that will show an ascending value in terms of the numberOfLikes. How can I get it so that it measures the numberOfLikes and numberOfComments and selects the most popular one?

Comment: What criteria are you using to gauge relative popularity?  Are you thinking of using something as simple as likes + comments, or are you weighting towards one or the other?

Comment: Weighing more likes than comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify whether you want to sort in ascending or descending order for each search field.

```
SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY `likesCount` DESC, `commentsCount` DESC
```

With that said, you won't be able to select the most like and most commented ones at the same time. You'll have to come up with a formula to figure that out. For instance, the example below find the maximum value for a given "id" between the number of likes and comments:

```
SELECT * FROM `db` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY GREATEST(`likesCount`, `commentsCount`) DESC
```

Another alternative would be to add them together:

```
SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY `likesCount` + `commentsCount` DESC
```

Comment: I just tried that and I am not completely sure that it works. I got the values `"numberOfLikes": "627", "numberOfComments": "100"` below the values `"numberOfLikes": "676","numberOfComments": "27"`

Comment: @XcodeDev - By using `GREATEST`, you can find out which the highest of both. Or adding should work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to order by total number of likes and comments? Does one of these weigh more than the other when it comes to popularity?

You could just do:

```
SELECT *, (`likesCount` + `commentsCount`) as popularity FROM db ORDER BY popularity DESC ...
```

As mistercruffles suggested below, you can add in a multiplier to have one factor weigh more than the other. Just change (`likesCount` + `commentsCount`) with (X*`likesCount` + Y*`commentsCount`) where X is the factor for likes and Y is for comments. For X = 2 and Y = 1, it means that likes are two times more important than comments, but I'm sure you figured that out.

Comment: You can even add in a multiplier to weight one or the other - for example, if you wanted to have a like be equivalent to two comments, you could use (2 * 'likesCount' + 'commentsCount').  There is a fascinating discussion here if you want to get a little more in-depth:  http://blog.linkibol.com/2010/05/07/how-to-build-a-popularity-algorithm-you-can-be-proud-of/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to weight likes more than comments, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY (3*`likesCount` + 2*`commentsCount`) DESC
```

Which will weight likes more than comments in a 3:2 ratio, i.e. 50% stronger. I'm not sure whether you want this or are would prefer to choose the higher of the two counts to rank by, but want to weight them before determining the higher of the two. If the latter is what you are looking for then this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `db` ORDER BY greatest(3*`likesCount`, 2*`commentsCount`) DESC
```

Comment: You can't use `MAX` that way.

Comment: @Francois: Sorry, you're right of course. I meant greatest. Should have checked that before answering, it's been a while...